# @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties vs babel-plugin-transform-class-properties

Tags: babeljs

what is the difference between these 2 babel plugins?

- @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
- babel-plugin-transform-class-properties.

Which one should I use?

After looking [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties) and [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) it's still not clear to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should use `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` because it is following current naming convention.

> Renames: -proposal-
>   Any proposals will be named with -proposal- now to signify that they aren't officially in JavaScript yet.
>   So @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties becomes @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties, and we would name it back once it gets into Stage 4.

from [We’re nearing the 7.0 Babel release. Here’s all the cool stuff we’ve been doing.](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/were-nearing-the-7-0-babel-release-here-s-all-the-cool-stuff-we-ve-been-doing-8c1ade684039)