# Unable to resolve Could not find plugin "proposal-class-properties"

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-start

I have cloned a new project and after npm install, when I m doing npm start getting bellow error.

"Could not find plugin "proposal-class-properties". Ensure there is an entry in ./available-plugins.js for it" I have searched for help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52501915/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties-vs-babel-plugin-transform-class-properti), but could not resolve.

It was told by my friend that he is not getting this error for the same project on hi environment.
Can someone help me in resolving this.[image]

Comment: could you paste the error logs which you are getting ?

Comment: @vidur In comments i can not past the complete log, i have attached a screenshot in the main question, please have a look. I m getting similar errors for several other files as well.

Comment: please check https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-install-missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a resolutions folder to package.json:

```
"resolutions": { "@babel/preset-env": "7.5.5" }
```

Then:

```
run npx npm-force-resolutions
```

Lastly run an npm or yarn install:

```
npm install
```